# Asus ROG GL752V Laptop stuck at Logo, wont POST, can't access to BIOS

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, motherboard, post

I've been having this problem after updating my laptops windows, when I turn it on, it won't go past the asus logo and I can't access to the BIOS either, I disassembled it and disconnected everything leaving only the RAM, the CMOS battery, the FAN, the power cord  connector and the screen connector connected to the motherboard, while I was writing this post I realized the battery charging LED blinks 4 times stops and then blinks 4 times again and so on without stopping, this blinking happens regarding the battery being connected or disconnected, is this an error code?

I have done the following:
Hard reset
Turning it on with and without the HDD
Removed the CMOS battery waited about 1 minute
Tested another ram stick and tested the original in other laptop and it works

I'm running out of options, if you guys have any recommendations or some troubleshooting steps I can follow i would be greatly thankful, in case you need more information I'll update this thread with what's requested, thanks a lot!

Comment: What colour is the blinking?

Comment: The colour is green

Comment: Try this "Please turn off the laptop (press and hold the Power button for 15 seconds until the Power light is OFF to force shut down) and remove the AC adapter, then press and hold the Power button for 40 seconds to do Hard reset."

Comment: If nothing helps, take it to a repair-shop.

Comment: Is there anything similar to a "motherboard-manual" for laptops?

Comment: I was able to access the bios and I could even install a new OS but accessing the BIOS is extremely slow, that's the problem now